# How to write elegant conditional bits of markup in Razor views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Suppose the following model:

```c#
public class ViewBookModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently rendering it like this in my Razor view:

```html
<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
@if (Model.Subtitle != null)
{ 
    <h2>@Model.Subtitle</h2>
}
```

My question is about the `Subtitle` bit. The above approach feels a little clunky, and can get repetitive (which is probably a bad sign) at times.

Are there any better, less verbose, more elegant ways to handle this situation?

---

I had considered (a) the option now mentioned in [Mat's Mug's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52019/10034), as well as (b) moving the condition to the model:

```c#
public class ViewBookModel 
{
    // ...
    public string ShowSubtitle { 
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Subtitle); } 
    }
}
```

With this change to the view:

```
@if (Model.ShowSubtitle)
```

However, that doesn't address my main issue: the verbosity (i.e. 4 lines of view code just to display `Subtitle`).

Comment: Have a look at [templated delegates](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/14/a-better-razor-foreach-loop.aspx/), so you can keep markup at the relevant places and move the logic to [extension methods](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/28/a-better-razor-isnullorempty-statement.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer was originally an [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/22967) to @EricB's post, but that edit got rejected by a mod, suggesting it was better suited as a competing answer. If this answer helps you, please consider responding to (upvoting ;)) [his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52020/10034).

---

If you find a pattern getting too repetitive, you can use @helper instead:

```
@helper ShowIfNotNull(string header) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header)) {
        <h2>@header</h2>
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```html
<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
@ShowIfNotNull(Model.Subtitle)
```

Alternatively, you can create an HtmlHelper extension that does the same thing:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ShowIfNotNull(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text, string tagName)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder(tagName);
        builder.SetInnerText(text);
        return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
@Html.ShowIfNotNull(Model.Subtitle, "h2")
```

Answer (score 24):

If you find a pattern getting too repetitive, you can use @helper instead:

```
@helper ShowIfNotNull(string header) {
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
        @:<h2>header</h2>
    }
}

<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
@ShowIfNotNull(Model.Subtitle)
```

Comment: Hadn't heard of `@helper` before, that's pretty useful.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice first post, I hope you keep reviewing! Feel free to meet the regulars in [chat] :)

Comment: Thanks again. After some tweaks for syntax (I've suggested it as an edit) this worked for me. I've also added a version that is exposed as an HtmlHelper extension, that allows you to choose the wrapper tag.

Comment: @EricB: Alas, my edit was rejected as "too radical". A fair point I guess, though if you agree with my suggestions feel free to merge it into yours and I'll happily change my "Accept" mark to your answer again and delete my own.

Comment: If you're going to use this helper method, at least name it `ShowIfNotNullOrEmpty` so it does exactly what it says... I would not recommend using this however: it's more code and moves markup out of context (you would have to switch back and forth to have an idea of the rendered markup).

Answer (score 6):

To give an alternate solution: you can do this with pure CSS3 using the `:empty` selector.

```css
h2:empty {
  display: none
}
```

The `:empty` selector will match on all empty tags. 'Empty' can include HTML-comments, but not whitespace.

[Here's a more detailed explanation.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/)

Comment: Outtathebox, +1! With the appropriate selector this may just work, and it's semantically quite "correct" for several of my cases.

Comment: could you add more explanation from the outside link into your answer, that way if the link dies the information is still here on the Answer

Answer (score 4):

`Subtitle` being a `string`, a *more elegant* way of testing whether it's `null` would be to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Subtitle)`, like this:

```
<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Subtitle))
{ 
    <h2>@Model.Subtitle</h2>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your review! I had considered this (should've had a "What I've tried" section in my question, I guess; but as an answer it may help future visitors here equally well). My *main* concern however was with the verbosity, as addressed by Eric B's answer.

Comment: Great! Feel free to give @EricB a well-earned checkmark :)